# Return Taxonomy/Term Information with Posts (WP_Query/get_posts)

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms, get-posts

Is it possible to return taxonomy/term information for posts along with the posts themselves when querying with get_posts?

I have around 150 items I am querying so I don't want to loop and pull each individually.

Comment: WordPress will cache all terms for the query by default. Calling `get_the_terms` etc. within the loop with not hit the database

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Even though it's a simple answer, you should post this as an answer so it can be accepted and not come up in the unanswered list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress will cache all terms for taxonomies attached to all post types in the query result set by default - well, so long as you haven't set either `cache_results` or `update_post_term_cache` to `false` ([codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Caching_Parameters)).

So calling `get_the_terms` etc. within the loop will not hit the database. **However**, `wp_get_object_terms` *will* hit the database as it by-passes WordPress' object cache.